# The Liitle Schemer 4th page103 value function

Tags: scheme

I got some problem on different platform.
This is my code:

```
(define o+
  (lambda (n m)
    (cond
     ((zero? n) m)
     (else (o+ (sub1 n) (add1 m))))))

(define value
  (lambda (nexp)
    (cond
     ((atom? nexp) nexp)
     ((eq? (car (cdr nexp)) 'o+)
      (o+ (value (car nexp))
          (value (car (cdr (cdr nexp))))))
     ((eq? (car (cdr nexp)) 'o-)
      (o- (value (car nexp))
          (value (car (cdr (cdr nexp))))))
     ((eq? (car (cdr nexp)) 'o*)
      (o* (value (car nexp))
          (value (car (cdr (cdr nexp))))))
     ((eq? (car (cdr nexp)) 'o/)
      (o/ (value (car nexp))
          (value (car (cdr (cdr nexp)))))))))
```

On chicken scheme :

```
(value '(1 o+ 1)) => 2
```

On mit-scheme:

```
(value '(1 o+ 1)) => ;Unspecified return value
```

Why?  It confuse me.

Comment: atom? is non-standard. What is the definition of atom? in MIT?

Answer (score 0):

Scheme is not a unique language, and the different implementations implement different versions. For this reason, not all the versions have the same set of predefined operators. For instance, `atom?` is one of this operators. In an implementation in which this operator is not defined, like in MIT-Scheme, you can use this definition:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (pair? x)) (not (null? x)))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it !   I love you !